# legend click in highcharts to disable other series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to disable or hide one series when other series is `hidden or disabled`.

Example: I have 3 columns cluster chart(ex: A,B & C) when I click on legend 'A', it should disable both series 'A' and 'C'.

I've tried `legenditemclick` event in `highcharts`, but I failed to get a hold on other series(C).

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at the linkedTo property: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.linkedTo  (by default it hides the legend entry for the linked series, but you can opt to show it still if you want, using the showInLegend property) | http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/0otmxgz7/